# Loading an Image in `<div>` overrides html text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing an html page that should have the following behavior:

1. When loaded it contains an empty `<div>` with a link inside it.

[image]

2. Once pressed the link runs the script `StartTrial.js` which is supposed to load an image from a directory, visualize it, and give some instructions on what to do.

[image]

However, as you can see, once the image is loaded it covers the instructions. This is cause the instructions are written in a `<div>` that has a margin of 30px from the container `<div>` with its size before loading the image. How can I fix my code so that the text is always shown with a 30px margin from the bottom of the image?

Here are my code snippets:

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
 <a href="javascript:StartTrial()" id="startTrial">Start Trial</a>
 <img class="displays" id="t1_img" src="./images/immi.jpg">
</div>

<div class="instruction" id="instr_1">
    <p><b>Instruction:</b><p> 
    <p>Some text here.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.displays {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function StartTrial() {

    $('#startTrial').hide();
    $('#t1_img').show();
    $('#instr_1').show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css to use min-height and min-width

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

and remove the absolute positioning, as there is no real need for it.

```
.displays {
    display: none;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Your image is larger than the container and hence it is overlapping the instructions.

Comment: Your solution works great, now the image doesn't overlap the text anymore once loaded. However, the container will extend horizontally till the very end of the page, so a limit on the `max-width` should also be set (i.e. `max-width: 300px;`). If an image is more than 300px large it will spill out of the box but nothing happens. Thanks!

Comment: If you are setting both min-width and max-width to 300px, then remove both and replace it with width:300px . Also do mark the answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to over-engineer it, you can have a css only solution or a simple JS one as follows:

**CSS only solution**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="startCheckbox" class="start-checkbox"/>
<div id="container" class="container">
     <label for="startCheckbox" class="start-trial center">Start Trial</label>
    <div class="instruction center" id="instr_1">
         <p><b>Instruction:</b></p> 
         <p>Some text here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    margin: auto;    
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.container .instruction {
    border: 1px dashed #333;
    background: rgba(255,238,221,.9);
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}


.container .start-trial {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container .start-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.start-checkbox {  
  display: none;
}
.start-checkbox:checked ~ .container .start-trial {
    display: none;
}

.start-checkbox:checked ~ .container .instruction {
    display: block;
}

.start-checkbox:checked ~ .container {
    background: url(http://www.ceritaspros.com/dev/images/dogs/FunnyPuppies/funny-puppies-sleeping-400x400.jpg);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qobbkh6f/5/

**CSS+JS Solution**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" class="container">
   <a href="#" id="startTrial" class="start-trial center">Start Trial</a>
   <div class="instruction center" id="instr_1">
     <p><b>Instruction:</b></p> 
     <p>Some text here.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
  margin: auto;    
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.container .instruction {
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  background: rgba(255,238,221,.9);
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.container.clicked {
  background: url(http://www.ceritaspros.com/dev/images/dogs/FunnyPuppies/funny-puppies-sleeping-400x400.jpg);
}

.container.clicked .start-trial {
  display: none;
}

.container.clicked .instruction {
  display: block;
}

.copntainer.clicked .instruction {
  display: block;
}


.container .start-trial {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#container").on("click", "#startTrial", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#container").addClass("clicked");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qobbkh6f/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it helps
HTML

```
<div id="container">
 <a href="javascript:StartTrial()" id="startTrial">Start Trial</a>
 <img class="displays" id="t1_img" src="./images/immi.jpg">
</div>

<div class="instruction" id="instr_1">
    <p><b>Instruction:</b><p> 
    <p>Some text here.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    background: grey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px;
    overflow:hidden
}

.displays {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Javascript

```
function StartTrial() {

    $('#startTrial').hide();
    $('#t1_img').show();
    $('#instr_1').show();

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jx3dn44/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute positioning on your image.

The whole concept of absolute positioning is to make an element overlap the other elements on the page. If you don't want something to overlap other elements then don't use it.

Also don't give a size to your container. It's not the container that's 300x300 and grey - it's your start trial block. If the container is invisible and flexible then it will look good with the image in it when you remove the start trial block. I forget how hide() works but just change to display:none if it doesn't actually remove the element from the layout.